# How to setup a custom board with a UCI chess engine (e.g. Stockfish)

Tags: uci

I am making a chess GUI that uses stockfish as the chess engine. I want to allow the user to set up a custom board (i.e. they can place piece arbitrarily on the board). How do I set up the internal board in stockfish so that the engine can make moves in the custom board?

I found on the UCI documentation:

"* position [fen  | startpos ]  moves  .... 
    set up the position described in fenstring on the internal board and
    play the moves on the internal chess board."
However, I can't seen to find what exactly the format of "fenstring" should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fenstring" is a special notation for chess positions called [Forsyth–Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) or short FEN.